# Is there any relation between particular integral's form and derivative of the complementary function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I read about the 'Method of undetermined' in the wikipedia

and it said as following:

---

In order to find the particular integral, we need to 'guess' its form, with some coefficients left as variables to be solved for. This takes the form of the first derivative of the complementary function. Below is a table of some typical functions and the solution to guess for them.

---

I can't understand the sentence "This takes the form of the first derivative of the complementary function"

what does it mean?

Is there any relation between particular integral's form and derivative of the complementary function?